# Uploading video through Laravel REST API and getting mimeType to be application/octate-stream

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

Environment:
Ubuntu 20.04
Nginx 1.18.0
Laravel 5.5

I'm developing a REST API in Laravel and trying to upload a video with it.

Nginx configuration is:

```
server {
root /var/www/domain/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
server_name domain.com;
client_max_body_size 15M;
client_body_buffer_size 1M;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 512k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 512k;
fastcgi_buffers 16 512k;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
location / {

        client_body_buffer_size 1M;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
        client_max_body_size 15M;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
# With php-fpm (or other unix sockets);
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
# With php-fpm (or other unix sockets);
client_max_body_size 15M;
}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbo
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

```
http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # set client body size to 2M #
    client_max_body_size 15M;

     server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

#   include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
#   default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I've also disabled the mimeTypes of Nginx.
When uploading short videos its working fine less than 1.5MB but when uploading video of above 1.5MB it's mimeType is becoming application/octate-stream.

I've also attached the Screenshot of Postman response.

For this request, video size is 117KB
[image: for this request, video size is 117KB]

For this request, video size is more than 2 MB
and mime type changed to application/octate-stream
[image]

[image]

Laravel Validation:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($this->_request->all(), [
                    'event_id'    => 'required',
                    'title'       => 'max:150',
                    'image_url.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
                    'video_url'   => 'mimes:mp4|max:152400',
                    'description' => 'max:1000',
                    'is_public'   => 'in:0,1',
                ]);
                break;
```

Can you suggest the issue, why it's behaving this way? and whether it's an issue from Nginx or Laravel.

Comment: And what's wrong with application/octet-stream for uploading binary data?

Comment: @Martin Zeitler I've mentioned in the screen shot, validation is failing, and I want the data in video/mp4 mime type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually problem was related to expired SSL Certificate, after successfully renewing the certificate the problem was solved.